# Why doesn't TestClass#foo work as expected? (Details and example below)

Tags: ruby

I'm not sure what's going on here or what to ask, really, so I had to write an example.

Expected behavior:

1. test.start is called
2. foo { bar } is called inside the start method
3. bar is called every 5 seconds, logging to the file each time; it does this 3 times in total

Everything works fine until point 3. Looking at the timestamps, foo.bar appears to get called every 5 seconds, but it doesn't output to the file until the loop has terminated. In effect, it logs to the file 3 times in succession after 15 seconds have elapsed.

```
require 'logger'

module Logging
  def logger
    Logging.logger
  end

  def self.logger
    @logger ||= Logger.new(STDOUT)
  end
end

class TestClass
  include Logging
  def initialize delay, log_path
    @delay = delay
    @log_path = log_path
  end

  def start
    File.delete @log_path if File.exist? @log_path
    exit if fork
    Process.setsid
    exit if fork
    Dir.chdir '/'
    STDOUT.reopen(@log_path, 'a')
    STDERR.reopen(@log_path, 'a')
    foo { bar }
  end


  def foo &block
    3.times do
      yield
      sleep @delay
    end
  end

  def bar
    logger.info(self.class.name) { "testing" }
  end
end

test = TestClass.new(5, "#{Dir.pwd}/test.log")
test.start
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? The foo method isn't redundant in the real code like it is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the output being buffered. You can force output to be written immediatley and not buffered with [`IO#sync=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-sync-3D).

For example:

```
STDOUT.reopen(@log_path, 'a')
STDOUT.sync = true
```